# Where to put client DLLs in n-tier architecture for calling external API

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

We have an n-tier architecture with a DAL -> BL -> UI, seperation. In our DAL we have EF for our database access.

We have a requirement to make calls to an external API from a different company. We have been given a couple of client .DLL files with libraries to make the process seamless.

We are struggling to decide where the .DLL files should reside. Should we put them in the DAL and then do the calls in the DAL because it is data access or should we put it all in the BL and make the external calls in there. Therefore not touching the DAL and keeping it isolated and solely for database access.

Would greatly appreciate any advise on this.

Comment: I think there is no clear" right or wrong" here and this is depending on your specific needs and opinion. IMO I would put them where you need them -> BL if you need the calls there...

Comment: The purpose of separating your persistence logic into a DAL in the first place is to make it possible to replace EF (in your case) with another provider. What ties this external API DLL to EF? Would it make sense to reimplement the API integration should you replace your ORM?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense. That being said the API stuff should be unaffected if we chose to swap out our ORM.

Comment: Normally I would add another layer named: External Layer (EL) which contains all the logic to call the external API's. The BL has a reference to EL. But if you want to stick to the 3-tier architecture, I would put it in the BL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it sounds like you should reference the external assembly on your data access layer beucase the main object of this assembly is to retrieve data. But, when you consume the data access layer on the business layer you also have this principal. I would go by Business Layer. Given it is *part of your logic*, then you should put this kind of access there.

**Another point**: If you are not comfortable to reference this assembly on you class library business layer project, you could abstract it into an interface and inject it (by IoC for sample) on your business layer. Using some approach like this, you will keep it on the business layer and isolated the access of this API.

For sample, add it on your Domain Model layer (if you are using one):

```
public interface IExternalDataService
{
   IEnumerable<SomeDto> Getdata();

   SomeDto Getdata(object id);
}
```

On an another class library project you add the refence of the assembly and make the API call, implementing this interface:

```
public class ExternalDataService : IExternalDataService
{
   public IEnumerable<SomeDto> Getdata()
   {
        // consume the API (dll) here...
   }

   public SomeDto Getdata(object id)
   {
        // consume the API (dll) here...
   }
}
```

On your BL classes, depend of the interface:

```
public class CustomerService
{
     public CustomerService(IExternalDataService externDataService)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to be clear of what exactly is the external DLL providing us, in most of the cases the external dll wraps up the business logic of that particular third party application.

Which, that's why in my opinion, should be kept along in the BL of your application. And hence agreeing with your last statement, to put DAL isolated just taking care of database operations.

Comment: There a 3 X dlls and they provide us back with a public piece of information. Inside these all the SOAP stuff is nicely hidden away. I just call a method and pass in parameters to get out response. I was leaning toward it being in the DAL, now I'm not so sure.

Comment: well my friend, since the dlls are just returning you some public piece and is something which does not invlove DB operations, then I would suggest you to go ahead and put them in BL only. Unless you got some other opinion.